# Gradle + Jenkins + Artifactory Pro: Release staging and promotion

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am new to setting up CI/CD process. Here is what I am trying to do

**Setup:**

1. I have a spring-boot application using gradle.
2. I have set up a scripted jenkins pipeline to build and upload the rpm as SNAPSHOT version to Artifactory, using the following tutorial (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins)
3. I have enabled the Artifactory addInteractivePromotion in my jenkins pipeline script.

Everything is good till this point, I am able to upload the artifacts to Artifactory under SNAPSHOT (snapshot-local) repo.

**Problem:**

The problem starts when I use the interactive promotion on Jenkins, when I promote the artifact (project-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.rpm), artifactory copies the SNAPSHOT version to release repo (release-local) without changing the version (project-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.rpm). I want to release this SNAPSHOT version (project-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.rpm) to release repo with a version changes (project-1.0.1.rpm). 
.rpm -> release-local

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

We ditched the interactive plugin and wrote our own script which will use the upload and download specs to promote artifacts from one repo to another.